# I am trying to delete an object in my trailhead playground to re take a lesson and get the following errors

Tags: custom-object, delete

Is there way to delete an object like a delete cascade approach. thx

```
Reason  Section
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Apex Class
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:PropertySummary" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:MortgageCalculator" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:PropertyTile" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:PropertyTileList" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:SmartHomeCard" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:SmartPriceCalculator" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:PropertyListDaysOnMarketChart" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:PropertyDaysOnMarketChart" - COMPONENT
This custom object is used by another feature. Remove the usage and try again.  Aura Component Bundle "c:DaysOnMarketEstimator" - COMPONENT
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you'll need to delete/modify each component before you can delete the main item you're trying to delete.